# WPF Custom Button And DependencyObject

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a custom `Button` with the property `ButtonTheme`.
This should be responsible for the Background of the Button. I want to set this in the XAML-code.

**My Custom Button**

```
public enum Theme
{
    Black,
    White
}

public class BugButton : Button
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public Produkte Product { get; set; }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonThemeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonTheme", typeof(Theme), typeof(Theme), new PropertyMetadata(Theme.Black, new PropertyChangedCallback(ValueChanged)));
    public Theme ButtonTheme
    {
        get
        {
            return (Theme)GetValue(ButtonThemeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ButtonThemeProperty, value);
            ValueChanged(this, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(ButtonThemeProperty, value, value));
        }
    }

    public BugButton()
    {

    }

    private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as BugButton;

        var brush = new ImageBrush();
        if ((Theme)e.NewValue == Theme.White)
        {
            brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/BugReport;component/Images/bug.png"));
            control.Background = brush;
        }
        else
        {
            brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/BugReport;component/Images/bug_black.png"));
            control.Background = brush;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClick()
    { 
        base.OnClick();
        BugWindow bug = new BugWindow(Email, Version, Product);
        bug.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void SetParameters(string aEmail, string aVersion, Produkte aProduct)
    {
        Email = aEmail;
        Version = aVersion;
        Product = aProduct;
    }
}
```

**How I Want To Call It In XAML**

```
<BugReport:BugButton x:Name="B_bug" ButtonTheme="White" Margin="0,8,8,0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderButtonHoverMakeover}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White"/>
```

**The Problem**
`The type "Theme" must be derived from "DependencyObject".`

So I guess it has to look like this:

```
public class BugButton : DependencyObject
```

But this does not work out with the things I need from the Button. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Clemens How would you do it instead?

Comment: It isn't necessary at all, because the PropertyChangedCallback is called by SetValue (because you have passed it to property metadata in the Register call). As another note, you should also write `var control = (BugButton)d;` instead of `var control = d as BugButton`, because that would correctly result in an InvalidCastException instead of a NullReferenceException in case it's not a BugButton.

Comment: Use Style and DataTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens Although I agree with you, is it really possible for `d` not to be `BugButton`? I mean is there a feasible scenario in which the framework calls this method with `d` of other type (I disregard explicit calls)?

Comment: @Grx70 Of course not. However, it's  a bad habit to *always* use the as operator instead of an explicit cast. Especially when you don't check the result for null.

Comment: @TomUnger It's also redundant to call `control.Background = brush` from both branches of the if block in ValueChanged.

Comment: @Clemens As I said, I totally agree with you and always prefer explicit casting over `as` operator where applicable. I was just wondering if there was some case I didn't know about because I always use explicit casting in dependency property changed callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got invalid argument in your [`DependencyProperty.Register`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms597502(v=vs.110).aspx) call, namely the third parameter `Type ownerType` should indicate the type that is registering the dependency property (the owner type) and not its value type (which is specified by the second parameter `Type propertyType`). Also, the owner type should derive from `DependencyObject`. Now you pass `typeof(Theme)` as the owner type (which it isn't), hence you get the error.

What you should do is pass `typeof(BugButton)` as the third parameter (`BugButton` is the actual registering type) instead:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonThemeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ButtonTheme",
        typeof(Theme),
        typeof(BugButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(Theme.Black, new PropertyChangedCallback(ValueChanged)));
```

Also, the call to `ValueChanged` in the `ButtonTheme` setter is redundant. It will be called by the framework upon calling `SetValue(...)` if the value has actually changed.

Comment: Nice, thank you! But the Button doesn't change when I start the program.

Comment: @TomUnger You've set `Background="White"` after `ButtonTheme="White"`, so what are you expecting?